# How to add foreach in controller codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this array in the codeIgniter controller to be pass on the view....

```
    $data['acquaintance_id'] = $facebook->api('/me/friendlists/acquaintances?fields=members{id}');
```

I would like to get the cover photo of each IDs in the array so I used foreach.

```
  foreach($data['acquaintance_id'] as $acq) {
      foreach($acq['members']['data'] as $acquaint) {

        $newID = $acquaint['id'];

        $data['acq_cover'] = $facebook->api('/'. $newID .'?fields=cover');

        }
      }
```

Then I tried to call the acq_cover in the View using

```
      print_r($acq_cover);
```

But I get an error stating

```
     A PHP Error was encountered
     Severity: Warning
     Message: Undefined index: acq
     Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
     Filename: controllers/Iconnect.php
```

What do I need to change in my code? Any answers/suggestions is highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: dump the variable before inner foreach

Comment: like var_dump($acq)? is that what you mean @mithunsatheesh

Comment: yes. put that in your question

Comment: I add var_dump on my code but it didn't work.

Comment: $data['acquaintance_id'] must be array. Try print_r($data['acquaintance_id']) die(). foreach accepts only array. if it'not array, problem should be facebook object

Answer (score 0):

problem is with

```
$data['acquaintance_id'] = $facebook->api('/me/friendlists/acquaintances?fields=members{id}');
```

line. $data['acquaintance_id'] doesn't get any value. So it's obvious that you can't foreach a null result. Try

```
$data['acquaintance_id'] = $facebook->api('/me/friendlists/acquaintances?fields=members{id}');
var_dump($data['acquaintance_id']);die;
```

once you debug that line, then remove the die; and comtinue.